# How to remove duplicates from a dataset in Java?

Tags: java, csv, duplicates, dataset

Let say a dataset is like this:

```
Sno  country  noOfDeaths
1    India    3245325
2    America  234523
3    UK       3432523
3    UK       3432523
```

Here `Sno` 3 is duplicated, I want to remove this entire row.

```
3    UK       3432523
```

This last line should remove.

Here is my code how I'm reading the dataset:

**data_reader.java**

```
public class data_reader {
    String filePath="src\\covid_19_data.csv";
    BufferedReader reader=null;
    String line="";
    
    public void readDataSet() {
        try {
            reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null) {
                String[] row=line.split(",");
                for(String index:row) {
                    System.out.printf("%-10s",index);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        }
        finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            
        
    }

        
    }
    
    
}
```

**main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        data_reader obj=new data_reader();
        obj.readDataSet();
}}
```

Please help how to do this.

**Update:**

```
public class data_reader {
    String filePath="src\\abc.csv";
    BufferedReader reader=null;
    String line="";
    String duplicateLine="";
    Set<String> idSet = new HashSet<String>();
    public void readDataSet() {
        try {
            
            reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));            
            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null) {
                String[] row=line.split(",");
                idSet.add(row[0]);
                

//              for(String index:row) {
//              System.out.printf("%-10s",index);
//              }
                System.out.println();
                
                
            }
System.out.print(idSet); 
            
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        }
        finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            
        
    }}
```

**output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, Sno]  it delete the last line which was duplicated
```

but how to print the output like this?

```
Sno  country  noOfDeaths
1    India    3245325
2    America  234523
3    UK       3432523
```

Comment: Your code is just reading and printing results, are you asking how to skip the duplicate line or do you want to actually modify the csv file and remove the duplicate line?

Comment: just skip the duplicate line

Comment: Try declaring a variable to store the read line, so you can compare it with the next line read, if they're the same then don't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

## Record

Define a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) to hold your data.

```
record Sample ( int sno, String country, long noOfDeaths ) {}
```

As a record, the compiler implicitly creates overrides of the `equals` and `hashCode` methods. Those methods’ implementations consider each and every member field.

## Set

Instantiate an object per row of input data. Collect into a `Set`. Sets disallow duplicate. Any duplicate being added is ignored.

```
Set< Sample > samples = new HashSet<>();
…
samples.add( new Sample( … ) ) ;
```

## `NavigableSet`

You may want to sort your distinct objects. Use a `NavigableSet` such as `TreeSet`, passing a `Comparator` object to specify the desired ordering.

The getter methods in a record share the same name as their respective member field. The getters in a record do *not* follow the JavaBeans’ naming convention of `get`/`is` prefix.

```
NavigableSet < Sample > samples = 
        new TreeSet<>( 
            Comparator.comparingLong( Sample :: noOfDeaths ) 
        );
…
samples.add( new Sample( … ) ) ;
```

Comment: how i'll be adding record in ```samples.add( new Sample( … ) ) ;``` line?  is it something like this ```samples.add( new Sample(row[0]) ) ;```  as row[0]=sno ?

Comment: @TimeToCode You instantiate a record by passing an input value for each member field in the order declared. Look at the linked Java JEP 395.

Comment: ```samples.add( new Sample(row[0],row[1],row[2]) ) ;``` u meant this? sorry for asking too much, i'm new to java!

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Set<Integer> idSet` where you put the Ids in.
If the `idSet.add()` method returns **`false`** delete the current line.

> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present (optional operation). More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if the set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2)). If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false. In combination with the restriction on constructors, this ensures that sets never contain duplicate elements.

Comment: I used set and it removed the value, but how to print the entire dataset after removing the values? please check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Here u go !

```
public class data_reader {
    String filePath="src\\abc.csv";
 BufferedReader br = null;
 HashSet<String> lines = new HashSet<>();
 String line = "";
    public void readDataSet() {
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (lines.add(line)) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (br != null) {
                    try {
                        br.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    
        
    }
```

**output:**

```
Sno,Country,noofDeaths
1,d,32432
2,f,32432
3,f,3332
```